# Conditional page scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a JSP page which contains a search field and under it a search results table. When the user presses the search button the request is processed through the java servlet and the page is reloaded with the returned results in the table. I need the page to scroll down to the table after the page loads ONLY after the search was complete.

I researched this topic and found this solution

```
onclick="document.getElementById('searchtable').scrollIntoView();"
```

I put this in the search button and it works but when the button is pressed the page gets reloaded, and the reloaded page starts from the top, which is my problem.

This is what I have

```
<div id="searchtable">  
<table>
<c:forEach items="${tableheader}">
<!-- search results go here -->
</c:forEach>
```

What I was thinking of doing is adding a

`<c:if test="${tableheader not equal null}">document.getElementById('searchtable').scrollIntoView();</c:if>`

into the `<c:forEach>`, but I am not sure how to properly implement this.

Any help would be great.

Comment: is `onclick` assigned to a button in a form

Comment: Yes it is  @Ramanlfc

Comment: if the page is reloaded and a table is generated, then you need to give the table an id and a # tag at the end of the url to take you to that section of the page. SInce this is not a async operation, that is what needs to be done.

Comment: So the div already has an id ("searchtable"), In the Java servlet I need to add #searchtable to the end of the page url in the requestDispatcher? so example 'getRequestDispatcher("search.jsp#searchtable");'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a general JSP

```
<form onsubmit='getTable'>
      <button type='submit'>Get Table</button>
</form>
```

so when you click, the page reloads, and a table is suddenly present, correct?

this can be fixed with JS like so:

```
<script>
      (function autoScroll(){
          document.getElementById('searchtable').scrollIntoView();
      })()
</script>
```

or rather, scroll to the table if it contains rows (with jQuery for ease)

```
<script>
      (function autoScroll(){
          if( $('#searchtable tbody tr').length > 0 ){
              document.getElementById('searchtable').scrollIntoView();
          }
      })()
</script>
```

Comment: you can add an onready function to determine whether the dom is ready, but that should be covered by the auto executing function being added at the end of the page